# Find users having all skills in passed array

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have an `skillSets` table which has below fields.

```
skillSets
-------------------------
userId -> multiple rows for same users

data: JSON {
skillId
}

type

clientId
```

I want all the users which have all skills in passed array.

So if a users has `skills a, b and not c it should be ignored for skills in (a, b, c)`.

But it should select users `which have skills a, b, c for skills in (a b, c)`

It should also select users `which have skills a, b, c, d for skills in (a, b, c)`

```
Select userid, data, type
from g.skillSets where
clientid='cce2032a-fd3d-48a1-8e4c-417eb77776c3'
and type = 'Skill Item'
AND JSONB_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(g.skillSets.data,'skillId') in ('72c28245-968f-11eb-b30a-87bc1ba467bd','84737607-968f-11eb-b30a-87bc1ba467bd','cca8631f-968f-11eb-b30a-87bc1ba467bd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `jsonb` containment operator `@>`:

```
... WHERE data @> '{ "skillId": [ "a", "b", "c" ] }'
```

A GIN index on `data` can support this condition.